# How can I get the first results of a Google Search that is not an ad using python?

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to get the financial statements of a bunch of Australian companies as pdfs. I have all the companies stored in a pandas dataframe, their company names are in a column called 'Companies' This is my code so far to search for the urls:

```
import webbrowser

tabUrl = "http://google.com/?#q="
append = "+financial+report+2017"
file_type = 'filetype%3Apdf+'

for company in data["Company"]:
        googleSearch = tabUrl + file_type + company.replace(" ", "+") + append
        print(googleSearch)
```

Every search returns (unsurprisingly) a number of ads as the first result. How do I open the first result that is not an ad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are sending request to the google webpage url and the results displayed would contain the ads that you see on google if you go to https://www.google.com

A better way to do this would be to use google [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to send your requests and get the results. You can get the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

From their documentation, you see that you can make `REST` requests to their service end point once you generate your **API KEY** and **Custom search engine ID**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```